# How do I stop the error overlay being shown in a react app?

Tags: reactjs

I've inherited a React app (it's custom react app using version react 17.0.2, not based off CRA), and when an error occurs the whole screen displays the error as shown. Is there a way to stop this? I have tried adding an ErrorBoundary, but while they seem to be executed the error is still displayed.

[image]

Comment: Is this error overlay from CRA we're talking about? If so, saying what version you use is probably a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, no, it's not CRA. It's a custom setup. Good point about the version. I've updated my question.

Comment: This is not something that's built into react. This is something your custom setup is doing. So it depends entierly on what that setup is.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that, just have to figure out what...do you think this looks like the CRA react-error-overlay? I searched the lock file and can't find that, but it seems like something similar.

Comment: Similar, but it looks different. Maybe there is a `window.addEventListener('error', ...)` somewhere in there. Or you can add an event listener like that and stop the event from propagating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the error overlay from Webpack's dev server, try to change your webpack configuration as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    client: {
      overlay: false,
    },
  },
};
```

(https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)

But why do you want to disable it? It is pretty useful and it is only present in development. You should of course also have error boundaries for production.

Comment: Is there a way to copy the error? Currently it displays but can't be accessed and highlighted by the mouse/